# Urbi "switch" statement error

Tags: robotics

I'm working on a project in Urbi for the Aibo ERS-7. Since Urbi 2 is not available for Aibo, I'm using the following:

```
URBI Language specif 1.0 - Copyright (C) 2005-2008 Gostai SAS
URBI Kernel version 1.5 rev. 51997ef
```

I'm wondering why the following code is generating an error. It is intended to make a random action when a loud noise is heard. The code is below.

```
motor on;
robot.initial();
robot.stretch();

whenever (micro.volume >= 1000)
{
  randomval = random(16);
  switch (randomval)
  {
    case 0: //LF1
      legLF1.val = (random(254) - 120);
    case 1: //LF2
      legLF2.val = (random(100) - 9);
    case 2: //LF3
      legLF3.val = (random(148) - 29);
    case 3: //RF1
      legRF1.val = (random(254) - 134);
    case 4: //RF2
      legRF2.val = (random(100) - 9);
    case 5: //RF3
      legRF3.val = (random(148) - 29);
    case 6: //LH1
      legLH1.val = (random(254) - 120);
    case 7: //LH2
      legLH2.val = (random(100) - 9);
    case 8: //LH3
      legLH3.val = (random(148) - 29);
    case 9: //RH1
      legRH1.val = (random(254) - 134);
    case 10: //RH2
      legRH2.val = (random(100) - 9);
    case 11: //RH3
      legRH1.val = (random(148) - 29);
    case 12: //neck
      neck.val = (random(80) - 2);
    case 13: //headTilt
      headTilt.val = (random(60) - 16);
    case 14: //headPan
      neck.val = (random(182) - 91);
    case 15: //mouth
      mouth.val = (random(55) - 58);
  }
};
```

The error that is generated is as follows:

```
/MS/clap.u:50.10: syntax error, unexpected (
[0000037549]!!! 22.1-15: Error loading file: clap.u
[0000037549]!!! 22.1-15: Error with function eval: U596213128.load [nb param=1]
[0000037549]!!! 22.1-15: EXPR evaluation failed
```

From what I understand, it doesn't like the parenthesis at the "switch" line. I don't really see reference to "switch" in the version I'm using, and it is highlighted as if it exists in the Gostai Editor, but there is no mention of it in any changelogs up to the newest version. Does it even exists, and if so, what am I doing wrong. In the case that it does not exist, should I just use a bunch of if statements (please, no).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed no switch/case in urbi 1.0.

A better alternative to a bunch of ifs is to use arrays to store the device and parameters:

```
var devices = [legLF1, legLF2, ...];
var ranges = [254, 100, ...];
var offsets = [...];

devices[randomval].val = random(ranges[randomval]) + offsets[randomval];
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  This is exactly what I needed. I'm a newer programmer, so I miss these subtle efficiency things.